# How can I add stickers to an image in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm working on a Swift iOS app where I want the user to be able to place an image (a sticker such as a beard or an eyepatch) over another image.

Currently I have it working to where they can take a photo or pull an image up from their Photos and have that display in a UIImage. Obviously next is adding the sticker. I've been able to dig up zero data on this from Google or Stack. And I mean zero.

Does anyone have a general idea of how I would execute this? Specifics would help too of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the easy way.

1. have a `UIView` as a parent, let's say `stickerView`
2. add image to `stickerView`
3. add stickers to `stickerView`
4. save a snapshot of `stickerView`

---

Here's the code to snapshot `UIView`,

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0)
        view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
}
```

---

Usage

`let snapshotImage = UIImage.imageWithView(stickerView)`

Comment: I have 1 and 2 working. My issue is with 3. I'd like the user to be able to tap on the screen and have the sticker appear where they tapped. Do you have a strategy for implementing this?

Comment: Make `stickerView` tappable by adding `tapGesture`. Get tapped position inside `stickerView`. Create a new sticker, set `center` to the tapped position, then add it to `stickerView`

Comment: For future users this tutorial is helpful: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Comment: What if the Image size is 800x800, but the stickerView size is 320x320. How to store image maintaining original resolution(800x800) with sticker added on top?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add UIImageView for sticker instead of editing image when adding sticker. And after that when save the image then you should edit the image.